# Error when inserting row into MySQL database from Python

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm trying to update an empty mySQL database using Python.

This is the error I receive:

> pymysql.err.InternalError: (1416, 'Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field')

Here's the problematic code:

```
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Create a new record
        sql = "INSERT INTO `projects` (`name`, `country`,  `activation_date`, `active`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('Nate', 'USA', '2016-06-23 09:11:32', '1'))

    connection.commit()

finally:
    connection.close()
```

Here is what the table looks like in the database (it's empty):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you include the table's definition (including indexes and triggers)? It's not quite obvious from your post what raises the error.

Comment: Yes, I think you're using the datatype [`LineString`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-linestring-property-functions.html) the wrong way and meant to use a varchar or text type. [A LineString consists of Points](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-linestring-property-functions.html) and is meant for spatial data, not text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the MySQL type `linestring` to represent a string, while in MySQL the correct type to represent a string of characters would be `text` or `varchar(<some_length>)`. `linestring` is a representation of a geometric line, as you can see here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-linestring-property-functions.html

To fix this, simply change the column types of `name` and `country` to `varchar(<some-length>)` or `text`. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html

Comment: Thanks everyone, this fixed it!